# Repeated measures anova and split plot design analysis

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, split-plot

It is mentioned that repeated measure anova may be very similar to split-plot design: 
[Is a "split plot" ANOVA with two factors the same as two-way ANOVA with repeated measures in one factor?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17378/is-a-split-plot-anova-with-two-factors-the-same-as-two-way-anova-with-repeated)

http://influentialpoints.com/Training/Split_plot_and_repeated_measures_ANOVA_use_and_misuse.htm

Is it possible to use following split plot analysis to the last example (rat liver glycogen vs food) of anova on this page: http://www.personal.psu.edu/mar36/stat_461/split_plot/split_plot.html

```
> library(agricolae)
> with(mydf, ssp.plot(rat, food, prep, method, glycogen))

ANALYSIS SPLIT-SPLIT PLOT:  glycogen 
Class level information

food    :  T1 T2 T3 
prep    :  P1 P2 
method  :  A B 
rat     :  Remy Templeton Scabbers Splinter Nicodemus Rizzo 

Number of observations:  48 

Analysis of Variance Table

Response: glycogen
                 Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
rat               5 4381.4  876.27 262.553 4.798e-06 ***
food              1   35.0   35.02  10.493   0.02297 *  
Ea                5   16.7    3.34                      
prep              1   54.2   54.19                      
food:prep         5   24.9    4.97                      
Eb                                                      
method            5  523.4  104.67                      
method:food                                             
method:prep                                             
method:food:prep                                        
Ec                                                      
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

cv(a) = 1.3 %, cv(b) = NA %, cv(c) = NA %, Mean = 138.8542
```

The output seems all right though the P value are different.