# What is the difference between a 2x2x2 split plot ANOVA and a 2-way repeated measures ANOVA?

Tags: anova, split-plot

What is the difference between a 2x2x2 Split-Plot ANOVA and a 2-Way Repeated Measures ANOVA?

Comment: Does this question help you: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17378/is-a-split-plot-anova-with-two-factors-the-same-as-two-way-anova-with-repeated?rq=1 If not, I think you should rephrase your question to ask for something more specific.